# Pipe console outputs from a specific function into a file - python

Tags: python, file, console-output

I have a function that I cannot edit and it prints results onto the console. Is it possible to calls that function but pipes the console output into a file without changing the internal code of the function?

For example, I have:

```
def somefunc(x):
  print "Hello World", x**x

def pipeout(func, outfilename)
  with open('outfilename', 'w') as fout:
    # somehow pipes out the output...
```

I couldn't use `logger` because I couldn't edit the `somefunc()`.

I have tried @Aशwini चhaudhary 's solution but i couldn't the files were empty other than the first outputfile and also it overwrites that file again and again.:

```
def redirect_output(file_name):
  def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
      with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        original_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = f
        func(*args)
      sys.stdout = original_stdout
    return wrapper
  return decorator

def somefunc(x):
  print x*x

xs = [1,2,3,4]

for i in xs:
  outputfilename = 'results/'+str(i)
  somefunc = redirect_output(outputfilename)(somefunc)
  somefunc(i)
```

Comment: why can't you edit the function. This is python and every function is in plain text files.

Comment: Might be a library function and needs to be used in some project that will get deployed. Of course you can edit it, but sometimes you should not.

Comment: yep, logically i can edit the function but it will cause all sorts of complication between me and the other developers and it's best to avoid merge conflict and fight over scrum meeting =)

Comment: @alvas Don't assign `somefunc` to a new function again and again inside the loop, either use a different variable name or directly call `redirect_output(outputfilename)(somefunc)(i)`

Comment: @alvas And use append mode `'a'` to prevent re-writing of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a decorator to redirect the `sys.stdout` to a file object when the function gets called and later restores it back to original STDOUT.

```
import sys

def redirect_output(file_name):

    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args):
            with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
                original_stdout = sys.stdout
                sys.stdout = f
                func(*args)
            sys.stdout = original_stdout
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@redirect_output('file.txt')
def somefunc(x):
  print "Hello World", x**x


somefunc(2)

print 'Hello to console.'
```

**Output:**

```
>>> %run so.py
Hello to console.
>>> !cat file.txt
Hello World 4
```

**Update:**

Working version of your latest code:

```
for i in xs:
  outputfilename = 'results/'+str(i)
  new_func = redirect_output(outputfilename)(somefunc)
  #or call it directly
  #redirect_output(outputfilename)(somefunc)(i)
  new_func(i)
```

Comment: The decorator, however, requires an extra level of indirection, since OP can't modify `somefunc`, I'd assume he also can't decorate it, so he'd need to write a decorated wrapper. And in that case, you might as well drop the whole decorator and just do the simple wrapper.

Comment: @JacobodeVera Well if they are importing the function from a module then they can use the other decorator notation: `somefunc = redirect_output('file.txt')(somefunc)`.

Comment: @Aशwini चhaudhary, i'm still having problems with the decorator solution, see updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the value of `sys.stdout` to another open file with write access. Then you can set it back with `sys.__stdout__`

I had this need a while ago and [made a context manager](https://github.com/jdevera/subdue/blob/master/test/utils.py):

```
import sys                                                                                                                          
from StringIO import StringIO 

class OutStreamCapture(object):
    """
    A context manager to replace stdout and stderr with StringIO objects and
    cache all output.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._stdout = None
        self._stderr = None
        self.stdout = None
        self.stderr = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        self._stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stdout = StringIO()
        sys.stderr = StringIO()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        """
        Restore original values of stderr and stdout.
        The captured contents are stored as strings in the stdout and stderr
        members.
        """
        self.stdout = sys.stdout.getvalue()
        self.stderr = sys.stderr.getvalue()
        sys.stdout = self._stdout
        sys.stderr = self._stderr
```

You can use it like this:

```
with OutStreamCapture() as osc:
    somefunc(x)
```

And then is `osc.stdout` and `osc.stderr` you have two strings with anything the function put in stdout and stderr, respectively.

This could be modified to use arbitrary files instead.

Please **note** that here I am caching the current value of `sys.stdout` in the context manager rather than using `sys.__stdout__` to restore. This is because at the point we enter this context, stdout might already be redirected, and we want to put it back to what it was.

Comment: i'm getting `AttributeError: __exit__` from the OutStreamCapture class

Comment: is it because py2.x doesn't have `__exit__` by default?

Comment: @alvas sorry, missed parentheses `with OutStreamCapture() as osc:`. Try it again please.